# What's the hierarchical relationship with UIView's root layer and root view?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer

I already know that UIView's subviews are arranged by their order.The latter has higher y-axis than the formmer.And the same goes for sublayers.The question is that what is the hierachical relationship between layer and view.Does view has higher y-axis than layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CALayer and its sublayers, if any, is a representation of a UIView, but not its subviews. Each subview has its own CALayer.

So if a UIView has subviews, these show above the UIView's layer and its sublayers.